# AWS lambda zappa not using latest boto3 version

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zappa

I have a flask app that I deploy to AWS lambda. This application requires the latest version of `boto3 (1.9.71)`, however, when deploying the application with `zappa` it does not use the latest version.

Here is the current setup:

```
from flask import Blueprint
import boto3

bp_routes = Blueprint('simple_routes', __name__)


@bp_routes.route('/test_boto')
def test_boto():
    return f'BOTO VERSION: {boto3.__version__}'
```

The `requirements.txt`:

```
flake8==3.7.7
Flask==1.0.2
flask-script==2.0.6
python-dotenv==0.10.1
yapf==0.27.0
zappa==0.48.2
botocore==1.12.71
boto3==1.9.71
```

Running the application locally with `flask run` and browsing to the route 
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/test_boto` I get

```
BOTO VERSION: 1.9.71
```

However, when deploying it to AWS lambda with `zappa update` and then browsing there I get

```
BOTO VERSION: 1.9.42
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: are you using a virtual environment to manage this?

Comment: Yes I'm using a virtual env for local dev

Comment: Are you packaging your version of boto3?  If not this link might help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: The packaging is done automatically by `zappa` so it should use the version specified in the `requirements`

Comment: try the ```zappa package``` command and then list the zip ```unzip -l file.zip|grep boto``` and check if/what version of boto is packaged. It might offer a clue

Answer (score 1):

Zappa excludes boto3 by default because its included in the lambda environment. A fudge that worked for me previously was add a pattern that won't match anything to the exclude field in zappa_settings.json this then caused zappa to include my bundled boto3.

Comment: Can you give an example of the `zappa_settings.json`?